# Navigation Bar Stays too far to the Right

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Edit: 
The problem is solved. Thank you for the help.

I seem to be having a problem getting my navigation bar to keep the width of the entire page and stay centered at the same time. It is a sticky navigation bar, and that part of it is working as intended. However, when the navigation bar locks into place, it doesn't lock all the way to the top as it is supposed to. The website is in very early development, but I really can't continue until I solve this mess. Feel free to ignore the sarcasm in some of my comment tags. It's how I vent frustration when working on something.

Links I've already visited to help:

1. [A Full-Width Centered Navigation Bar](http://www.cssnewbie.com/full-width-centered-navigation-bar/#.WI-_z8srKUk)
   I commented out all of my Navigation CS, and replaced it with theirs. It makes a great centered navigation bar, but it does not span the whole width of the page like I desire. I physically want the links to stretch across. Altering the 800px value to anything else forced the links to the left side of the screen.
2. [Bootstrap navbar will not center no matter what](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14888324/bootstrap-navbar-will-not-center-no-matter-what)
   When following the instructions of setting all padding to 0, all it accomplished was shrinking the overall height of the navigation bar.
3. [Why is right-aligned text in my navbar shifted too far to the right?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28982176/why-is-right-aligned-text-in-my-navbar-shifted-too-far-to-the-right)
   Not entirely related, but I figured it could shed some light on my problem. All it did was point out a bug in the bootstrap version the user was using. I am not using bootstrap myself.
4. [Why won't my navbar center?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24560076/why-wont-my-navbar-center)
   One of the comments suggested using a negative margin left number. This did have a positive effect, though I'd rather solve the root of the problem than use a hotfix.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>The Den</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen, projection" href="style.css">
  <script type ="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
  <script type ="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <!-- It would be nice to know if tables are what's throwing off my entire website or not... but whatever. -->
    <div class="status"></div>
    <div class="container"><!--I'll change the word "container" to Logo perhaps in the future here if I can get this example to work for once. Also let it be noted that I am in fact not using the "header" tag at any portion during this... which is bothersome. -->         
        <center><a href="http://www.wolvesofthedust.com/"><img src="http://i1288.photobucket.com/albums/b494/ShadowfangInnovia/WolvesoftheDustSiteHeader_zpsdddba823.png" height="auto" width="940" border="0" alt=" photo WolvesoftheDustSiteHeader_zpsdddba823.png"/></a></center>

        <!-- The navigation portion... dear God... here is where it all usually goes wrong. -->
        <nav>
            <ul class="clearfix"> <!-- Clearfix?! Really?! I'm ASSUREDLY changing that one. -->
                <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link 5</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link 6</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link 7</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link 8</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link 9</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav><!-- End the hiddeously named section... and hopefully begin progress towards a complete page... -->

        <br/><br/>
        <center><h2>THIS WEBSITE IS UNDER CONSTRUCTION!!! TAKE NOTHING HERE YOU SEE SERIOUSLY FOR THE TIME BEING!!!</h2></center> <!-- This is where I will likely have the table located with nicely written dialogue... but if the table isn't needed above then I may as well continue this practice elsewhere. Did I learn all about tables and arranging code properly for nothing? -->
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <p><!-- Interestingly enough it took me a while to realize that P stood for paragraph... considering people normally only wrote a single sentance per line with a "p" tag. Stupid examples and my insinuations based on them -->The lazy dog jumped over the quick brown fox. Yes I just did that. Deal with it. This is my website after all.</p>
        <p>The lazy dog jumped over the quick brown fox. Yes I just did that. Deal with it. This is my website after all.</p>
        <p>The lazy dog jumped over the quick brown fox. Yes I just did that. Deal with it. This is my website after all.</p>
        <p>The lazy dog jumped over the quick brown fox. Yes I just did that. Deal with it. This is my website after all.</p>
        <p>The lazy dog jumped over the quick brown fox. Yes I just did that. Deal with it. This is my website after all.</p>
        <p>The lazy dog jumped over the quick brown fox. Yes I just did that. Deal with it. This is my website after all.</p>
        <p>The lazy dog jumped over the quick brown fox. Yes I just did that. Deal with it. This is my website after all.</p>
        <p>The lazy dog jumped over the quick brown fox. Yes I just did that. Deal with it. This is my website after all.</p>
        <p>The lazy dog jumped over the quick brown fox. Yes I just did that. Deal with it. This is my website after all.</p>
        <p>The lazy dog jumped over the quick brown fox. Yes I just did that. Deal with it. This is my website after all.</p>
        <p>The lazy dog jumped over the quick brown fox. Yes I just did that. Deal with it. This is my website after all.</p>
        <p>The lazy dog jumped over the quick brown fox. Yes I just did that. Deal with it. This is my website after all.</p>
        <p>The lazy dog jumped over the quick brown fox. Yes I just did that. Deal with it. This is my website after all.</p>
        <p>The lazy dog jumped over the quick brown fox. Yes I just did that. Deal with it. This is my website after all.</p>
        <p>The lazy dog jumped over the quick brown fox. Yes I just did that. Deal with it. This is my website after all.</p>
        <p>The lazy dog jumped over the quick brown fox. Yes I just did that. Deal with it. This is my website after all.</p>
        <p>The lazy dog jumped over the quick brown fox. Yes I just did that. Deal with it. This is my website after all.</p>
        <p>The lazy dog jumped over the quick brown fox. Yes I just did that. Deal with it. This is my website after all.</p>
        <p>The lazy dog jumped over the quick brown fox. Yes I just did that. Deal with it. This is my website after all.</p>
        <p>The lazy dog jumped over the quick brown fox. Yes I just did that. Deal with it. This is my website after all.</p>
        <p>The lazy dog jumped over the quick brown fox. Yes I just did that. Deal with it. This is my website after all.</p>
        <p>The lazy dog jumped over the quick brown fox. Yes I just did that. Deal with it. This is my website after all.</p>
        <p>The lazy dog jumped over the quick brown fox. Yes I just did that. Deal with it. This is my website after all.</p>
        <p>The lazy dog jumped over the quick brown fox. Yes I just did that. Deal with it. This is my website after all.</p>
        <p>The lazy dog jumped over the quick brown fox. Yes I just did that. Deal with it. This is my website after all.</p>
        <p>The lazy dog jumped over the quick brown fox. Yes I just did that. Deal with it. This is my website after all.</p>
        <p>The lazy dog jumped over the quick brown fox. Yes I just did that. Deal with it. This is my website after all.</p>
        <p>The lazy dog jumped over the quick brown fox. Yes I just did that. Deal with it. This is my website after all.</p>
        <p>The lazy dog jumped over the quick brown fox. Yes I just did that. Deal with it. This is my website after all.</p>
        <p>The lazy dog jumped over the quick brown fox. Yes I just did that. Deal with it. This is my website after all.</p>
        <p>The lazy dog jumped over the quick brown fox. Yes I just did that. Deal with it. This is my website after all.</p>
        <p>The lazy dog jumped over the quick brown fox. Yes I just did that. Deal with it. This is my website after all.</p>
        <p>The lazy dog jumped over the quick brown fox. Yes I just did that. Deal with it. This is my website after all.</p>
        <p>The lazy dog jumped over the quick brown fox. Yes I just did that. Deal with it. This is my website after all.</p>
        <p>The lazy dog jumped over the quick brown fox. Yes I just did that. Deal with it. This is my website after all.</p>
        <p>The lazy dog jumped over the quick brown fox. Yes I just did that. Deal with it. This is my website after all.</p>
        <p>The lazy dog jumped over the quick brown fox. Yes I just did that. Deal with it. This is my website after all.</p>
        <p>The lazy dog jumped over the quick brown fox. Yes I just did that. Deal with it. This is my website after all.</p>
        <p>The lazy dog jumped over the quick brown fox. Yes I just did that. Deal with it. This is my website after all.</p>
        <p>The lazy dog jumped over the quick brown fox. Yes I just did that. Deal with it. This is my website after all.</p>
        <p>The lazy dog jumped over the quick brown fox. Yes I just did that. Deal with it. This is my website after all.</p>

    </div>
```

CSS:

```
    html {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #000;
}

body {
    font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 93%;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    padding: 40px 0;
    margin: 0;
    color: #7d0000;
}

a,
a:link,
a:visited {
    color: blue;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {margin-top: 0;}

p {margin: 0 0 1em 0;}

.container {
    max-width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 20px;
    position: relative;
}

h1 {
    background-color: #305782;
    color: #FFF;
    padding: 60px 25px;
    margin: 0;
}

nav {
    z-index: 500;
    background-color: #000;
}

.nav-placeholder {
    margin: 0 0 40px 0;
}

.fixed {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #000;
}

.fixed .nav-inner {
    padding: 0 20px;
}

.fixed .nav-inner-most {
    max-width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: #000;
}

nav ul {
display: table;
width: 100%;
list-style: none;
}

nav ul li {
display: table-cell;
text-align: center;
}

nav ul li a:link,
nav ul li a:visited {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 10px 25px;
    background-color: #000;
    border: 2px solid #7d0000;
    color: #7d0000;
    font-size: 90%;
    font-weight: bold;
}

nav ul li a:hover {
    background-color: #28bfa1;
    color: #FFF
}

/* This seems to have an undesired effect, but may be necessary for later.
   The border-right: none; attribute is especially annoying...

nav ul li:last-child a:link,
nav ul li:last-child a:visited {
    border-right: none;
}

*/

.clearfix:before, .clearfix:after { content: ""; display: table; }
.clearfix:after { clear: both; }
.clearfix { *zoom: 1; }
```

JS:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    // define variables
    var navOffset, scrollPos = 0;

    // add utility wrapper elements for positioning
    jQuery("nav").wrap('<div class="nav-placeholder"></div>');
    jQuery("nav").wrapInner('<div class="nav-inner"></div>');
    jQuery(".nav-inner").wrapInner('<div class="nav-inner-most"></div>');

    // function to run on page load and window resize
    function stickyUtility() {

        // only update navOffset if it is not currently using fixed position
        if (!jQuery("nav").hasClass("fixed")) {
            navOffset = jQuery("nav").offset().top;
        }

        // apply matching height to nav wrapper div to avoid awkward content jumps
        jQuery(".nav-placeholder").height(jQuery("nav").outerHeight());

    } // end stickyUtility function

    // run on page load
    stickyUtility();

    // run on window resize
    jQuery(window).resize(function() {
        stickyUtility();
    });

    // run on scroll event
    jQuery(window).scroll(function() {

        scrollPos = jQuery(window).scrollTop();

        if (scrollPos >= navOffset) {
            jQuery("nav").addClass("fixed");
        } else {
            jQuery("nav").removeClass("fixed");
        }

    });

});
```

Additionally, here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Shadowfang/Lgr24gm3/11/) and the website: http://www.wolvesofthedust.com/

Comment: Add `padding:0;margin:0;` to `nav ul`

Comment: Thank you! I can't believe I overlooked something this small.

Comment: @Shadowfang I know that it works now, but please consider posting the answer (on behalf of Michael Coker) and marking it as correct.

Comment: @xlm I did as such. I was actually wondering how to do this properly, thus the edit to the initial post. Thank you for clearing it up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was answered in a comment from Michael Coker.

Add `padding:0;margin:0;` to `nav ul`

Thank you again :)